# pandas. Изменить значение int на дату

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть Excel файл с выгрузкой из системы, кривоватая..
Во-первых, все колонки с датами выгружаются с "зеленым треугольником" (как неопределенный формат).
Во-вторых, если дата исходного заказа отсутствует она выгружается, как 00000000..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите заменить 00000000 на пустую ячейку, а даты превратить в формат дат.
Pandas изначально их воспринимает как int

С другими колонками, где нет 00000000 получилось справиться так:

```
order_df['ord_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(order_df['ord_Date'].str[:4] + '-' + order_df['ord_Date'].str[4:6] + '-' + order_df['ord_Date'].str[6:8])
```

Сразу оговорюсь, функция pd.to_datatime выдавала некорректные значения.
Например, дата (с "зеленым треугольником") 20220707 после обработки функцией превращалась в 1970-01-01 00:00:00.020220707. Установка разных форматов дат тоже не дала результата.

Пробовала через if, не работает:

```
if order_df.ord_Orig_Date == 0:
        order_df['ord_Orig_Date'] = None
    else:
        order_df['ord_Orig_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].str[:4] + '-' + order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].str[4:6] + '-' + order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].str[6:8])
```

Ошибка: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Пробовала через Numpy, не работает:

```
order_df['ord_Orig_Date'] = np.where(order_df['ord_Orig_Date'] != 0, 
                            pd.to_datetime(order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].str[:4] + '-' + 
                                           order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].str[4:6] + '-' + 
                                           order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].str[6:8]), None)
```

Ошибка: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?

Пробовала и так:

```
order_df['ord_Orig_Date'] = np.where(order_df['ord_Orig_Date'] != 0, 
                            pd.to_datetime(order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].astype(str).str[:4] + '-' + 
                            order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].astype(str).str[4:6] + '-' + 
                            order_df['ord_Orig_Date'].astype(str).str[6:8]), None)
```

Ошибка: File "", line 3, in raise_from dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: day is out of range for month: 0-- present at position 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используем `pd.to_datetime()` с указанием формата и параметром обработки ошибок `coerce`. "Неправильные" даты станут `NaT` - *not a time*, которые далее заменяем на ''.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['00000000', 20220707, 0, '20220709']})
df.Data = pd.to_datetime(df.Data, format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce').dt.date.replace({pd.NaT: ''}) # или .fillna('')
print(df)
```

```
         Data
0            
1  2022-07-07
2            
3  2022-07-09
```

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ! Вы не представляете как помогли!